# Magento 2 : How to get order collection group by customer?

Tags: magento2, customer, sales-order, customer-group, order-collection

To get order collection by customer wise i.e.., customer A and customer B have placed order and it should retrieve by customer wise per collection?

```
public function getOrdersByCustomer() {  

    $collect = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');

    $collection = $collect->getSelect()->group('customer_id');

    return $collection;
}
```

The above returns null.Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to get customer's order data?

Comment: No, I want to fetch the order collection group by customer_id. Hope you understand the question?

Comment: Please share full code .Seems code is right

Comment: That's it from block and retrieving on phtml

$_ordersbycustomer = $block->getOrdersByCustomer();
print_r($_ordersbycustomer->getData());
exit();

Answer (score 1):

Try using these cods:

```
 public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll try it out and let you know.